# Beginner CryptoGram - Msgs From Your Puzzle Community

Tags: cipher

I like simple ciphers. Here is one, no tricks, alpha-numeric substitutions only:

[image: Crypto]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this says

> MODS STOP PUTTING ME ON HOLD PLZ.

Though, ironically,

> there are lots of other ways to fill in the letters so as to make words, especially if we consider things like PLZ words ... so maybe this should be put on hold as "too broad"? :-)

Comment: funny... how did you do that so quickly.   OH BOY HERE WE GO Gareth.... smile. Can you please change my username to " 2Broad"  ?

Comment: With a little help from quipqiup.com, that's how. (Though it doesn't think of PLZ as a word.)